# Constant ICMP echo request sequence number - no response

Tags: ping, internet-security, icmp

I wrote a program which (in an infinite loop) sends an ICMP echo request packet (the packet consists of IP header and ICMP header only), waits for some time and then receives an ICMP echo reply packet sent by the server (if there's any).

When the wait time is quite long (~10s), everything works as expected - my program sends the packet, waits and then, after the wait time, the reply is ready to be received by the program. The problem appears when I set the wait time to less than 5 seconds (obviously it's still much more than the ping time): the first loop iteration works as it sould but on every subsequent iteration I don't get any ICMP echo reply packets. The problem only appears when ICMP headers of all the packets my program sends are the same - when the headers have different sequence number set the problem disappears (for every request there comes a response).

I've googled a bit but I haven't found any explanation of this phenomenon. Is the server or one of the routers on the path to the server blocking my packets because of the same content coming in too short time intervals? Is it some sort of anti-ping-flood-attack system?

Comment: Did you try Wireshark? What does it say?

Comment: I used tcpdump - it show no response packages for my requests (except for the first one of course).

Comment: Does operation system's `ping` command work with the same target?

Comment: Yes, ping works correctly but the packages it sends have different sequence numbers - in this situation my program also works.

Comment: Perhaps the destination host ignores those packets as duplicates? After all, that's what the sequence number is for...